# PHP Session not working and immidietly expires

Tags: session, php

I'm new to PHP and I learn sessions right now, so I tried to to create two files, one that creates the session var and one who prints it.. here's the code:
session1.php

```
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['a'] = 1;  echo 'The session right now is: ' . $_SESSION['a']; ?>
```

session2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['a']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['a'];
}
else
{
echo 'but the output here is false';
}
?>
```

First I enter to session1.php to create the session, then I go to session2.php and the output is false..
This only happens when this files are uploaded to the web hosting, you are welcome to try it yourself in this url: wwww.pzwhatsup.com/session1.php and wwww.pzwhatsup.com/session2.php.
When trying this in my computer with wamp, it works perfectly..

Comment: What does `var_dump(session_status());` show?

Comment: why in session1.php output is 1? if the code you posted is the exactly from that file, then it shouldn't echo anything.

Comment: Yes, make the code you put here match your pages exactly.

Comment: Yes I've edited this just now..

Comment: You mean `var_dump($_SESSION['a']);` ? it shows NULL

Comment: the PHPSESSID is there, I am sure that there is something wrong in second file, can you create new file from scratch and just write: `<?php session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION); ?>`

Comment: The output is `array(0) { }`

Comment: can you zip those files and provide the download link?

Comment: check your php.ini to see where your sessions are stored and whether you have proper permissions on them or not.

Comment: Yes of course: [link](https://mega.co.nz/#!wxogEaiD!H0Jk9hJ34u3eoelZCaGIWVH9KjNw5YLZs1Y3pWRmpmE)

Comment: Probem solved: I talked with the web hosting company and they tolled me that they havent set the session save path. Now they did this and it solved. Thank you all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your hosting company allow Sessions, and did they give a valid path with the proper rights for storing the sessions?

It happens.

Else, do you request the two files right after each other (include or somthing), or is there a page switch in between?

Cause when you set a Session value and request it right after (miliseconds) your value isn't always set properly.

Comment: It is set properly, if writing to the session array, then the content is locked. Meaning you will read from the old "status", that's where the session_write_close function kicks in ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some web hosters dont create the session's repertory, so try to read your webhoster's terms of using, maybe you would find something about creating your own session repertory.